# Cypress environment variable undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress

In cypress.json file i have the following code

```
{
  "baseUrl": "test",
  "ignoreTestFiles": [],
  "viewportHeight": 768,
  "viewportWidth": 1024,
  "video": false,

  "env": { "email": "test@email.com", "password": "password" }
}
```

When i am trying to access it by calling Cypress.env('password') it shows undefined in console log when printing it, what is the issues.

```
const password: string = Cypress.env('password')

describe("Login to the application", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/");
  });

  it.only("user should login successfully", () => {
    console.log(Cypress.env('email')).   --- undefined 
    loginPage.login(email, password);
    cy.url().should("include", "/wallet");
  });
```

Comment: Why not use `console.log(password)` instead?

Comment: For me Cypress.env('email') gives back test@email.com.
Where is your cypress.json located? It should be in the top cypress folder, not the bottom one

Comment: @PhilipAllStar yeh that was the case the file was placed in wrong directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake for not knowing or not checking the location of my cypress.json file, moved it to the top cypress folder and value is shown properly.

Comment: Please mark this answer as solution, because now this question it still displayed as unresolved.

Comment: Thank you so much, Artjom Prozorov for the answer  God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

In my Projekt (Version 10.xx) the cypress.config.ts must be in the root path not in the cypress folder. You can generate the config with the UI, to get it on the right location:
Settings > Project settings > cypress.config.ts

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE for CYPRESS V10.**

Extending @Artjom Prozorov's answer,

we have to use `cypress.config.(js|ts)` as the file name for configuration.

sample of file content is given below.

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "src/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001",
    trashAssetsBeforeRuns: false,
    viewportWidth:1920,
    viewportHeight:1080,
    slowTestThreshold: 1000,
    // watchForFileChanges : false,
    env: {
      apiUrl : "http://localhost:3000",
      commandDelay: 100,
      password: 'here it is'
    },
    reporter: 'mochawesome',
    reporterOptions: {
      reportDir: 'cypress/reports',
      overwrite: false,
      html: true,
      json: false
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env.sharedSecret =
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'itsDev' : 'itsLocal'

      return config
    }
  },

  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "create-react-app",
      bundler: "webpack"
    }
  }
});
```

NOTE : this cypress.config.ts must be **inside** the cypress directory.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this is true. The new convention still requires the cypress.config.(js|ts) file to be in the top level folder and not inside the cypress/ folder, as you have mentioned.

Comment: yes, you are correct.